# Как проверить элемент на принадлежание к классу?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, menu

Появился вопрос, как организовать проверку на наличие класса у элемента.
Начальный код примерно такой.

```html
        <div id="SmartMenu">
            <div id="MenuIcon" onclick="DoIt(this)">
                <div id="strip1"></div>
                <div id="strip2"></div>
                <div id="strip3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Это — иконка меню. Выглядит так изначально:

[image: Изначальное меню]

Далее я сделал код, который её поворачивает после нажатия.

```css
function DoIt(icon) {
    icon.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

После чего иконка становится такой:

[image: Повёрнутое меню]

Так как у меня оно должно открывать выпадающий список, я должен ввести проверку класса, т.к. у повёрнутого меню добавляется класс: `class="changed"`.
В HTML я пишу следующий код:

```html
       <div id="OpenMenu">
            <ul id="OpenMenuList">
                <li class="OpenMenuLink"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Text</a></li>
                <li class="OpenMenuLink"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Text</a></li>
                <li class="OpenMenuLink"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Text</a></li>
                <li class="OpenMenuLink"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Text</a></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
```

Изначально элемент с `id` `OpenMenu` имеет `display: none;`.
Потом при нажатии на иконку меню должен меняться класс у этого элемента и появлсяться `display: flex;`. Вот, что я имею на данный момент, но оно, разумеется, не работает.

```css
var Icon = document.getElementById("#MenuIcon");


if (Icon.classList.contains("change")) {
    function Down(menu) {
        menu.classList.toggle("then");
    }
}
```

Что делаю не так и как исправить? Также необходимо, чтобы вылезало меню плавно, а то так, как я сейчас делаю: оно будет просто появляться. И ещё. Оно не должно сдвигать никакие элементы. Оно должно быть ниже элемента с `id` `SmartMenu`, но на остальные элементы на страничке оно может наезжать. Также меню не должно быть фиксированным, чтобы при прокрутке странички оно оставалось сверху.
Всё делается под смартфоны, поэтому и запарился с таким меню.

```js
function DoIt(icon) {
    icon.classList.toggle("change");
    var Icon = document.getElementById("MenuIcon").className;

    if (Icon == "change") {
        function Down(menu) {
            document.getElementById("OpenMenu").className = "than";
        }
    }
}
```

Не меняет класс у элемента с `id` `OpenMenu`, что делаю неверно?

```js
function DoIt(icon) {
    icon.classList.toggle("change");
    var Icon = document.getElementById("MenuIcon").className;

    document.getElementById("OpenMenu").className = "then";
}
//Сделал так, но почему-то всё равно не меняется у OpenMenu класс
```

Понял, что вопрос сложный и непонятный. Дополню стилями для всех элементов.

```css
/* MENUS */

#SmartMenu {
    top: 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    width: 98%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    height: auto;
    background: rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.6);
}

#MenuIcon {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 30px;
}

#strip1, #strip2, #strip3 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    margin: 14px 0;
    transition: .3s;
}

.change #strip1{
    transform: rotate(90deg) translate(24px, -24px);
}

.change #strip2{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.change #strip3{
    transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-24px, 24px);
}

#OpenMenu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.6);
    transition: .5s;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-radius: 16px;
}

.then #OpenMenu {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#OpenMenuList {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.OpenMenuLink {
    font-style: 10pt;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    color: #09df6d;
    transition: color .4s linear;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0 15px;
}

.OpenMenuLink:hover {
    color: #9bff8b;
}
```

Comment: Ну у Вас открывалось то, что было самой иконкой меню. Попробовав переделать под свой лад я понял, что у меня не выходит. И задал более подробный вопрос. Вот и всё...

Comment: Дал правильный ответ, потому что попробовал у Вас и увидел, что всё работает. Только после этого попробовал у себя.

Comment: Хм, я нажал стрелочку вверх, но мне сказало, что я чего-то там не достиг. Невнимательно прочитал Ваш ответ.

Comment: Вопрос простейший, просто Вы его меняете по 10000 раз, что не приемлемо.

Comment: Почему неприемлимо? Вы не понимаете, я пытаюсь объяснить!

Answer (score 1):

```
    function DoIt(icon) {
        icon.classList.toggle("change");
        var Icon = document.getElementById("MenuIcon").className;

        if (Icon == "change") {
            document.getElementById("OpenMenu").className = "than"; // Тут наверно не than, а then как в начальном примере. Убедитесь, что такой класс у Вас существует в css.
            function Down(menu) { // В Вашем коде отсутствует вызов функции down, по этому и не срабатывает. Переместите за функцию.
                menu.classList.toggle("then");
            }
        }
    }
```

У Вас в примере, `OpenMenu` не имеет стиля. 
Вот пример, если у Вас стоит стиль `display: none;` (Тогда его надо сначала удалить или изменить)

```js
function DoIt(icon) {
    icon.classList.toggle("change");
    document.getElementById("OpenMenu").removeAttribute('style');
    document.getElementById("OpenMenu").classList.toggle("then1");
}
```

```css
.change{
    color: #fc2601;
}
.then1 {
    color: #0f00ff;
    display: none;
}
.then then1 {
    color: #0f00ff;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="SmartMenu">
<div id="MenuIcon" onclick="DoIt(this)">
    <div id="strip1">123</div>
    <div id="strip2"></div>
    <div id="strip3"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="OpenMenu" class="then">
<ul id="OpenMenuList">
    <li class="OpenMenuLink"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Text</a></li>
    <li class="OpenMenuLink"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Text</a></li>
    <li class="OpenMenuLink"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Text</a></li>
    <li class="OpenMenuLink"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Text</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы менялся класс у определённого объекта-то?

Comment: document.getElementById("id объекта").className = "название нового класса";

Comment: Сейчас дополню вопрос, а то что-то не работает.

Comment: @KoryJaxx Дополнил ответ с комментарием.

Comment: Опять не выходит, снова дополнил.

Comment: @KoryJaxx Дополнил ответ........

Comment: А зачем Вы в SmartMenu вписываете что-либо? SmartMenu — это лишь иконка меню, которая меняется при нажатии. Я в вопросе скинул 2 скриншота. До нажатия и после. Если нажать 3-й раз — она возвращается "на исходную".
Так вот, сам вопрос был в том, чтобы не трогая иконку и никак её не разворачивая: плавно, не выходя за рамки странички, выезжало меню. Так называемый "выпадаемый список". Я сейчас дополню вопрос кодом стилей, который использую для всех элементов, что указаны в вопросе. И да, когда меню закрывается (3-е нажатие) — список тоже должен "заезжать" обратно и скрываться.

Comment: @KoryJaxx, дополнил ответ - остальное оформляйте отдельно. Вы 1000 вопросов задаёте в одном вопросе. Вопрос был как проверить элемент на наличие классу. Ответ - вот так:     var Icon = document.getElementById("MenuIcon").className;

    if (Icon == "change") { код} После этого Вы ещё кучу вопросов задаёте.

Answer (score 0):

Вы функцию `Down` в проверке объявляете, а не запускаете.

```js
var icon = document.querySelector(".menuIcon");
var menuList = document.querySelector(".menuList");

function change() {
    icon.classList.toggle("change")
    menuList.classList.toggle("showed")
 }
```

```css
.menuIcon {
 cursor: pointer;
 background: lightGreen;
 user-select: none; /*просто для убоства*/
}

.change {
 background: red;
}

.menuList {
 display: none;
}

.showed {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <span class="menuIcon" onClick=change()>menu icon</span>
    <ul class="menuList">
        <li class="menuLink"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Text</a></li>
        <li class="menuLink"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Text</a></li>
        <li class="menuLink"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Text</a></li>
        <li class="menuLink"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Text</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```